# idiomatic way to only update the first elem matching a pred in a coll

Tags: clojure

I have a seq, `(def coll '([:a 20] [:b 30] [:c 50] [:d 90]))`

I want to iterate through the seq, and modify only the first element that matches a predicate.

The predicate `(def pred (fn [[a b]] (> b 30)))`

`(f pred (fn [[a b]] [a (+ b 2)]) coll) => ([:a 20] [:b 30] [:c 52] [:d 90])`

f is the fn I want, which takes a pred, and a fn to apply to the first elem which matches the pred. All the rest of the elems are not modified and returned in the seq.

What is the idiomatic way to do the above?

Answer (score 5):

One possible way is to split the collection with `split-with`, apply the function `f` to the first element of the second collection returned by `split-with`, and `concat` the elements together again.

```
(defn apply-to-first [pred f coll]
    (let [[h t] (split-with (complement pred) coll)]
        (concat h (list (f (first t))) (rest t))))
```

Note that the `pred` function in your example should probably look like this:

```
(def pred #(> (second %) 30))
```

Comment: Bonus: This solution is lazy.

Answer (score 4):

As with most problems, there is a number of ways to solve it. This is but one of them.

If you're running Clojure 1.5, give this a try:

```
(reduce
 (fn [acc [a b]]
   (if (pred b)
     (reduced (concat (:res acc) [[a (+ b 2)]] (rest (:coll acc))))
     (assoc acc
       :res (conj (:res acc) [a b])
       :coll (rest (:coll acc)))))
 {:coll coll :res []}
 coll)

;; ([:a 20] [:b 30] [:c 52] [:d 90])
```

The key in this algorithm is the use of the `reduced` (note the 'd') function - it essentially tells `reduce` to halt the iteration and return the result. From its doc string:

```
-------------------------
clojure.core/reduced
([x])
  Wraps x in a way such that a reduce will terminate with the value x
```

The code is a bit terse, but it should give you the basic idea.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

This function is not hard to write recursively "from scratch". Not only is this a good learning exercise, it also produces the best solution: it is as lazy as possible, and does the absolute minimum amount of computation. So far, only one answer to this question is lazy, and that one calls `pred` twice on all the items before the update occurs: once in the `take-while`, and once in the `drop-while`, parts of `split-with`.

```
(defn update-first [pred f coll]
  (lazy-seq
   (when-let [coll (seq coll)]
     (if (pred (first coll))
       (cons (f (first coll))
             (rest coll))
       (cons (first coll)
             (update-first pred f (rest coll)))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep it straightforward: find first element, find its index and use assoc to "update" the element at index:

```
(let [e (first (filter pred coll))
      ind (.indexOf coll e)] 
  (assoc (vec coll) ind ((fn [[a b]] [a (+ b 2)]) e) ))
```

Dominic's note about pred applies:

```
(def pred #(> (second %) 30))
```